# A third-grade teacher/student! Does it speak of her quality or designation?

Tags: word-choice, ambiguity

Whilst we all know that *grade* also refers to the intensity/degree of quality, I got this doubt looking at Jim's comment [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19560/how-to-tell-past-tense-when-we-met-to-someone). Although, looking at his sentence, it's clear that he's talking about the teacher teaching students of Grade IV.

In India, *standard* is more common as compared to *grade* for schooling. And it does not create ambiguity because if the thing is of top quality, it's of standard quality but then if it is not, it's **substandard** and not second, third or fourth standard. If you put adjective *first, second, third...* and the like to the word *standard*, it **always refers to schooling**.

The ambiguity rises when we use *grade*. If I call someone *A third grade* often in anger or sarcasm as in [here](http://www.mumbaimirror.com/entertainment/tv/Boli-ke-peeche-kya-hai/articleshow/15681873.cms) - it simply means **dumb, manner-less, awkward* person. So, if I want to refer to some teacher/pupil as a wicked person with third grade quality, how do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the US, each year of schooling is known as a grade.  Thus a *Third-Grade Teacher* is one who teaches children in their third year.

It is not a term of abuse.

In other countries there are equivalents used such as *third form* or simply *third year*.

As others have said, a derogatory term would be *third rate*.  A badly performing teacher could conceivably be described as a *third rate third grade teacher*.  A description which might be seen as having some poetic beauty.

Comment: +1 for *...a third rate third grade teacher.* clear it is! :)

Comment: You could also use your own suggestion, "substandard" - a "substandard third-grade teacher."

Answer (score 4):

If you want to insult someone, the proper term is *third-rate*, which typically appears in attributive position before a noun.  In contrast, a third grade teacher teaches a class of third graders.

"Third grade" as an insult is non-standard.  If it'll be understood where you are, you can of course go ahead and use it, but don't assume it'll be universally understood.